# Can ZXing.Net be used to interpret barcode from scanner?

Tags: c#, vb.net, zxing, zxing.net

I've been trying to research some ZXing.net examples for barcode scanning and all that I have come up with so far is examples that scan the barcode from an image.  Is ZXing.net capable of interpreting the scan from any generic (non-image based) barcode scanner?  Are there any examples out there that I just haven't found yet?

Comment: Are you looking for an example how to interpret the result string after barcode scanning (f.e. interpreting as vCard or vEvent data)?

Answer (score 1):

ZXing is an image processing library. It is not built to handle hardware scanners.

If you are looking to use a hardware barcode scanner, you should try to get hold of the driver for it.

In terms of using barcode scanners in .NET, I've had much success looking for scanners that have [OPOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPOS) (OLE for Retail POS) drivers available and using [Microsoft's Point of Service for .NET](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42081).

The OPOS drivers talk to the hardware and Microsoft POS is what allows your application to talk to the OPOS drivers. This is not limited to barcode scanners, but also allows you to talk to Magstripe Readers and other point of sale devices in .NET.

Comment: Are you aware of any barcode scanners off-hand that utilize the OLE for Retail POS drivers?

Comment: @CurlyShuffle the one I used previously was I think this one http://www.codecorp.com/products.php?id=91 Not sure on the model specifically, but they worked fine. I am not endorsing or recommending them. They were just what my previous employer purchased before I was hired. You should be able to verify what drivers are available before needing to purchase. I don't recommend buying before being able to verify and any company in that field should have a sales number you can call to quickly get an answer.